# Transform row into column and vice-versa using sql - oracle

Tags: oracle, pivot

I have this table:

```
create table history (
     date_check DATE, 
     type VARCHAR2(30), 
     id_type NUMBER, 
     total NUMBER
)
```

Selecting.....

```
select * from history order by 1

DATE_CHECK  TYPE    ID_TYPE TOTAL

14/02/2016  abc     1       14
14/02/2016  abc33   1       14
14/02/2016  bbb     1       40
14/02/2016  bbb33   3       43
14/02/2016  ddd     2       61
14/02/2016  ddd33   2       62
15/02/2016  abc     1       33
15/02/2016  abc33   1       44
15/02/2016  bbb     1       55
15/02/2016  bbb33   3       66
15/02/2016  ddd     2       77
15/02/2016  ddd33   2       88
```

Type its always this 6 values:

```
abc
abc33
bbb
bbb33
ddd
ddd33
```

And I cross this data with "id_type" so there is a decode like this:

`select type || decode(id_type, 1, '- new', 2, '- old', 3, '- xpto') as type from history order by 1`

In the end I need something like this:

```
DATE_CHECK  abc - new   abc33 - old     bbb - new   bbb33 - old ....

14/02/2016  14          14              40          43
15/02/2016  33          44              55          66
```

What is the easiest way to do it? Using pivot?

Comment: what is your Oracle **server** version?

Comment: Hello MaxU, it's 11g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
with data as(
select date_check, type, total from (
      select date_check, type || ' ' || decode(id_type, 1, '- new', 2, '- old', 3, '- xpto') as type, total from history
))
select * from data
pivot(
  max(total) for type in ('abc - new', 'abc33 - new', 'bbb - new',
                          'bbb33 - xpto', 'ddd - old', 'ddd33 - old')
)
order by date_check;
```

And for the "vice versa" use [UNPIVOT](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1#unpivot)

Answer (score 1):

You can reference multiple columns in a pivot statement to get your desired output.  In your case you have a single analytic column (TOTAL) but multiple columns forming composite columns on which to perform the analytic function, you can use a pivot query like the following:

```
select * 
  from history
  PIVOT ( max(TOTAL)
          for (TYPE, ID_TYPE) in ( ('abc',1) abc_new
                                 , ('abc',2) abc_old
                                 , ('abc',3) abc_xpto
                                 , ('abc33',1) abc33_new
                                 , ('abc33',2) abc33_old
                                 , ('abc33',3) abc33_xpto
                                 , ('bbb',1) bbb_new
                                 , ('bbb',2) bbb_old
                                 , ('bbb',3) bbb_xpto
                                 , ('bbb33',1) bbb33_new
                                 , ('bbb33',2) bbb33_old
                                 , ('bbb33',3) bbb33_xpto
                                 , ('ddd',1) ddd_new
                                 , ('ddd',2) ddd_old
                                 , ('ddd',3) ddd_xpto
                                 , ('ddd33',1) ddd33_new
                                 , ('ddd33',2) ddd33_old
                                 , ('ddd33',3) ddd33_xpto
                                 )
        )
```

You can adjust the output column headings to suite if desired by changing them similar to the following:

```
  ...
  PIVOT ( max(TOTAL)
          for (TYPE, ID_TYPE) in ( ('abc',1) "abc - new"
                                 , ('abc',2) "abc - old"
                                 , ('abc',3) "abc - xpto"
                                 , ('abc33',1) "abc33 -  new"
                                 , ...
```

Comment: Your solution works too! I'm sorry, I've got to pick one answer.. Thanks mate! :)